# Checking if a substring occurs in a separate column

Tags: r, substring, string-matching

I need to check whether my data contains names that a benchmark study doesn't.
The problem that I have is that my names are truncated, so are generally a substring of the names reported by the benchmarking study.

For example, a truncated version of my data:

```
      Benchmark             `My Data`
Southern Corp                Avista
American Electric Power      Atmos
Atmos Energy                 Southern
Delta Natural Gas Co Inc     DUET
Avista Corp                  Duke Energy
Duke Energy Corp             American Electric
Pepco Holdings               Nextra Energy
```

For example, you can see that in "My Data", the name is reported as "Southern", but in the Benchmark it is reported as "Southern Corp", similarly, my data will report "Duke Energy" as "Duke Energy Corp".

I need to find out whether my data set contains any names that the benchmarking set doesn't.

So I'd need a flag or a helper column which tells me that my data set includes "Nextra Energy", but the Benchmarking doesn't.

I want the output like:

```
    Benchmark               `My Data`            Not in Benchmark
Southern Corp                Avista                      0
American Electric Power      Atmos                       0
Atmos Energy                 Southern                    0
Delta Natural Gas Co Inc     DUET                        1
Avista Corp                  Duke Energy                 0
Duke Energy Corp             American Electric           0
Pepco Holdings               Nextra Energy               1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat$flag <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(any(grepl(dat$Data[i],dat$Benchmark))){
    dat$flag[i] <- 0
  } else{
    dat$flag[i] <- 1
  }
}

dat
                 Benchmark              Data flag
1            Southern Corp            Avista    0
2  American Electric Power             Atmos    0
3             Atmos Energy          Southern    0
4 Delta Natural Gas Co Inc              DUET    1
5              Avista Corp       Duke Energy    0
6         Duke Energy Corp American Electric    0
7           Pepco Holdings     Nextra Energy    1
```

Comment: Nice! You used the fact that the entry in the Data column will always be smaller and contain the substring that I'm looking for in the Benchmark column, right? I haven't seen any() used like that before either. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Since we get a TRUE or FALSE result for every element of `Benchmark` for each element of `Data` we can use `any` to make the result TRUE (and thus 0) as long as there is at least 1 match. Happy to help.

Comment: I was wondering if there could be any adjustment to this code to take into account differences in capital letters. For example, I applied your suggestion to my data and it works great except for when I have a name like "Nisoft" in the Data column and "NiSoft" in the Benchmark column. I was wondering how I'd apply some sort of regex based fix to this?

Comment: FYI got around the above issue by making everything lower case.